# Constructing a Collection of Sets Satisfying Certain Intersecting Properties

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I am trying to solve the following problem. We would like to construct $\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$, where $n$ is even, and each $A_i \subseteq [m]$, with $|A_i| = k$ and $m = \text{poly}(n)$. Now, I would like the following to be true:

1) $A_{2j} \cap A_i = \emptyset$ for $1 \leq j \leq n/2$ and for $1 \leq i < 2j$

2) Every other pair $A_i$ and $A_{j}$ with $j \neq i$ has a non-empty intersection.

I can solve this problem with $k = n/2$, but I would like a solution that is asymptotically better than linear in $n$ - ideally something like $k \in O(\log n)$. What is the smallest value of $k$ for which this is possible? I suspect that $k \in O(1)$ isn't.

PS: I am also accepting suggestions for a more descriptive (better) title.